# How to warn on a test failure from an outside influence using MSTest/CCNet

Tags: web-services, mstest

We have a section of our online service that integrates with a third party webservice. So we have a large number of unit tests using MSTest in Visual Studio 2010 that make sure that our transactions with the third party result in the expected responses. We run CCNet for continuous builds and it has been great doing exactly what continuous integration is meant to do. On many occaisions it found out when checkins in upstream layers altered the data on our end of the service and broke the integration.

Unfortunately the third party's integration test host is unreliable in that it can be down for maintenance without warning. So there are several times a day when the build will become broken due to these Unit Tests failing with connection problems. This is very distracting and there is nothing we can do about it except mark this as an acceptable result path. A lot of our test therfore look like the following:

```
var client = new ThirdPartyClient(TestConfig);
var Result = client.DoSomethingOverThere(ourDataToSend);
Assert.IsFalse(Result == BadResult)
Assert.IsTrue((Result == Success) || (Result == Timeout))
```

I'd really like to know which of the two possible results caused the test to pass. (In reality I wish that there was a way to use Assert.Inconclusive without it counting as a broken build) But does anyone have any recommendations on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This post addressing [Inconclusive Tests in TFS Build Should Not Break the Build](http://blog.dbtracer.org/2011/02/27/inconclusive-tests-in-tfs-build-should-not-break-the-build/) is explaining a workaround that might be applicable for your situation. I agree that setting the Inconclusive state to the test when your other party has problems is a pragmatic way of dealing with this issue.